# pdf - insufficient permission for image extraction

Tags: c#, pdf, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

I'm trying to convert a PDF to a tiff using the acrobat SDK's JSObject.  My code below:

[image]

The above code works for the majority of PDF files, but files with security/password protection fail.  An acrobat window pops up with the message "Insufficient permission for image extraction."
The security settings on my test PDF look like this:

[image]

I'm finding it difficult to find anything of use on the Adobe site/forums. Does anyone know of a means to programmatically enter a password for these types of files?

Comment: Please remove the image of the code and post the code itself as a text.

Comment: Do you know the password? That security flag means the document's creator has forbidden what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger I know the password for the document. In the application I'm writing the password will be prompted for.

Comment: AFAIK, using the API you can only de-password files by running a batch script on them from inside Acrobat. There is no external means within the SDK for password removal (a plugin would be a different story). There may be a library out there that does it, but I don't think Adbos SDK has that functionality.

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger Thanks.  It's less a case of removing a password, more of entering one so that I can invoke the "saveAs" function without receiving the permissions error.